# How to get maven dependency tree for specific project

Tags: maven, dependency-tree

I have created two projects (myproject1 and myproject2). myproject1 has some 3PPs and myproject2 also having some 3PPs. 3PPs could be same or not as we don't have control on this. myproject1 is using myproject2 as compile time dependency. Can I get dependency tree for myproject1 only ?

[Snippet for requested dependency tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzxg7.png)

in this image, blue cross sign indicate that these dependencies are not required.

Comment: I don't think so. What problem do you want to solve with this?

Comment: Lets say, organization XYZ running multiple projects. Assume myproject2 is reusable components specific to organization. myproject2 also using 3PPs and which are already evaluated from license and security perspective. Now myproject1 want to use myproject2 and myproject1 will add some 3PPs. Here myproject1 team will evaluate only those 3PPs which are used in myproject1.

Comment: Sounds like it would be better to just have a company-wise list of evalutated third-party JARs instead of doing it projectwise.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-810

Comment: It is just my humble opinion, but that feature request is rather difficult to understand and rarely useful to anyone (besides you), so do not expect that it will ever be implemented.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.